# Sorting using php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

.Hi guys, i need a little help with a project that i'm currently working on.

I have this database where i have a table containing records of students from different departments namely:

```
Dept1
Dept2
Dept3
Dept4
Dept5
```

in my batch.php i have two dropdown menus for Batch(which is the name of the tables) and Department(a field used for sorting).

what i want to do is that when the user chooses a Batch and a Department and then clicks the submit button, it will automatically assign the values chosen to a `MySQL` query for the `SELECT` method. the SELECT query should now retrieve all records from the table sort it by department but will display first the Department that was chosen above.

.Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance and more power!

Comment: So what are you having trouble with? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by a boolean expression, which will return 1 when true and 0 when false.

```
<?php
    $batch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['batch']);
    $department = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['department']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `" . $batch . "`" .
        " WHERE department = '" . $department . "'" .
        " ORDER BY department = '" . $department . "' DESC, department;
?>
```

Update: You should validate the `$batch` argument that it is a valid table expected, the code as is is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: .I'm sorry there was a mistake, please check out the question again I have already edited it.

Comment: .what is the function of DESC, department; in your code? also what do you mean by the code is vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Comment: @zerey `DESC` = descending, we want the department that does match to show up on top. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection